# How to have more of one classes with selector lang in css?

Tags: html, css, web, sass, less

hey I have a spa application and using i18n with 4 languages
I want to have a clear code in my CSS

```
html[lang|="ar"].test { a }
html[lang|="tr"].test { a }
html[lang|="ar"].test1 { b }
html[lang|="tr"].test2 { c }
```

I write like this but I want to merge them in one section like this :

```
html[lang|="ar"] --> { .test{a} .test2{b} }
html[lang|="tr"] --> { .test{a} .test2{c} }
```

it's possible to write all CSS of my tr lang in one section?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest CSS selector but you may use the selector `:is()` or `:where()` .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

here an example

```css
:where([lang|="ar"], [lang|="tr"]).test {
  color: red
}

:where([lang|="ar"].test, [lang|="ar"].test1) {
  font-weight: bold
}

:where([lang|="tr"].test1, [lang|="tr"].test2) {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<span lang="ar" class="test">hello</span>
<span lang="ar" class="test1">the</span>
<span lang="tr" class="test1">world</span>
<span lang="tr" class="test2">!</span>
```